# replace zero(integer) with space(string) with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calculating age from DOB but while i am returning value it show '0' for more see below code

```
 var birth  = new Date('DOB');
 var curr  = new Date();
 var age; // this is integer type in database
 if(birth != null)
 {
     var diff = curr - birth;
     age= Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
 } else {
     age=' ';  // while i return space from here it shows '0' on my output 
 }
```

How i can show space insted of '0'

Comment: Your code is incomplete, so there's little to work with here.  Where is `R2` coming from?  What is `AGE` vs. `age`? How about `birth`?  How are you outputting this?

Comment: Remove `else` block and add `if (AGE === 0) AGE = '';`

Comment: what is the value of 'birth' ?

Comment: Don't write your own date logic. Use a library like moment.

Comment: my application technology have some problem with  library like momen

Comment: If `age` is an integer in the database then why do you want to put a string `" "` in it?

Comment: on my  out put screen it show '0' and for other calculation i need 'age' as integer

Answer (score 0):

replace it `'null'` to `null`. null it is not string.

```
var curr  = new Date();
 var age; // this is integer type in database
   if(R2 != null && R2 != undefined )
   {
       var diff = curr - birth;
   AGE= Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}else
 AGE=' ';  // while i return space from here it shows '0' on my output 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did as little modification to your code as I could to not modify it's structure. The main change is to check if `age` is zero or less than zero, because the original code did return `0` or even *negative numbers* if the birth date was in the last year or in the future. This should work.

```
var birth = new Date('DOB');
var curr = new Date();
var age; // this is integer type in database
if (birth != null)
{
    var diff = curr - birth;
    age = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
    if (age < 1) {
        age = ' ';
    }
} else {
    age = ' ';  // while i return space from here it shows '0' on my output 
}
```